# Im trying to print the amount of every verible from input, but my code doesn't write what I want it though it seems right. python

Tags: python, string

Here is thecode and it keeps giving me the same thing though it should give a different output.

```
    line = input('Car: ')
    while line:
      def word_count(str):
      counts = dict()
      words = str.split()

      for word in words:
          if word in counts:
              counts[word] += 1
          else:
              counts[word] = 1

      return counts 
    line = input('Car: ')

  print( word_count(line))
```

Here is the output I get:

```
    {}
```

Comment: That indentation is not valid, could you edit it so it's clear what lines are part of the word_count function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
line = 'temp'
while line:
    line = input('Car: ')
    def word_count(str):
        counts = dict()
        words = str.split()

        for word in words:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1
        return counts

    if line:
        print(word_count(line))
```